# How do I pause to inspect results of sh commands run by a Makefile?

Tags: debugging, makefile, printing, mingw

So, I have a Makefile which runs different commands of how to build S/W. I execute `make` from within a MSYS / MinGW enviroment.

I found for example, the `sleep <seconds>` command, but this only delays the execution. How can I make it wait for a key being pressed, for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `read` command. When you are done you press enter and your script/makefile continues. It's a builtin bash command, so it should work also on MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

My proposition doesn't stop execution but halts and resume display on capable terminals:

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-S for halting display, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-Q for resuming.

You don't need to modify your Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the output of the build through more (or less)

e.g.

```
make <make command line> | more
```

Answer (score 0):

Or output everything to a file while still watching make progress on screen with your friend *tee*. I normally prefer this to *less* or *more* for bulkier projects.

```
make <make input arguments> 2>&1 | tee /some/path/build.log
```